# How can I make this "if" statement more clean and efficient?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

I'm trying to optimize/clean the "if" statement. As you can see the code, it looks... pretty long and inefficient. If you were me, how would you fix and make it look/work better?

To explain about what I'm trying to build :

- when the score is 5, I would like to push star icon 5 times to the "stars" array,
- when the score is 4, I would like to push star icon 4 times to the "stars" array,
- when the score is 3, I would like to push star icon 3 times to the "stars" array,
- when the score is 2, I would like to push star icon 2 times to the "stars" array,
- when the score is 1, I would like to push star icon 1 time to the "stars" array.

Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai";

const Review = ({ title, comment, score }) => {

  let stars = [];

  if (score == 5) {
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
  }

  if (score == 4) {
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
  }

  if (score == 3) {
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
  }

  if (score == 2) {
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
  }

  if (score == 1) {
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
  }

 
  return (
    <div className="review-container">
      <p>Title: {title}</p>
      <p>Comment: {comment}</p>
      {/* <p>Score: {star}</p> */}
      {stars.map((star) => star)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Review;
```

Comment: So you want to push a number of star icons equal to the score into the stars array? How do you normally repeat something a number of times?

Comment: Cough cough loops cough cough

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a `for`-loop. It pushes the `stars` as often as your `score` high is.

The `let i` in the for-loop is just the iterator it counts up to the point int reaches your `score`-variable.

So if your `score` is 5, it makes 5 times `push` and if your `score` is 1, it makes 1 `push`.

```javascript
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai";

const Review = ({ title, comment, score }) => {

  let stars = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < score; i++)
  {
    stars.push(<AiFillStar />);
  }

  return (
    <div className="review-container">
      <p>Title: {title}</p>
      <p>Comment: {comment}</p>
      {/* <p>Score: {star}</p> */}
      {stars.map((star) => star)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Review;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need any for loop or useState. It can solve simply by ES6

```
import React from "react";
import { AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai";

const Review = ({ title, comment, score }) => {
  return (
    <div className="review-container">
      <p>Title: {title}</p>
      <p>Comment: {comment}</p>
      {Array.from(Array(score).keys()).map((star) => (
        <AiFillStar key={star} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Review;
```

Comment: Thank you for your briliant solution, I tried yours, but it doesn't work properly.. Can you modify a little bit more?!..

Comment: Could you describe what is the problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
let stars = [];
stars.fill(<AiFillStar />, 0, score)
```

Please refer to [MDN array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) documentation.

Then you can `.map()` over `stars` array as you like.

Or even

```
[].fill(<AiFillStar />, 0, score).map(star => star)
```

Comment: This is briliant!! I've never seen it before! But I must try!! Thx for the answer!! :)